# Deploy Laravel (backend) and React (frontend) HEROKU

Tags: javascript, android, laravel, heroku

I have laravel app (rest api) and react/js app (client side). I would like to deploy them on heroku. Its possible to reach that with putting them into one git repo and deploy? I tried to use post-install scripts but it didn't work. enter code here

> EDIT. Added nodeJS buildpack (node installed on server) but it seems that Laravel covers react
>   pages with `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.`

Comment: Hi, were you able to get it done? I'm facing the same issue here close to a year later

Comment: The same is needed to me also.  Yet the question is very old. Yet, were you able to get it done?


Also @heroku members? Any way from your side ??

Answer (score 1):

Just enter this code to your `web.php`:

```
Route::get('{reactRoutes}', function () {
return view('welcome');})->where('reactRoutes', '^((?!api).)*$');
```